# Block internet traffic

Tags: port-forwarding, internet, account-restrictions

How does one disable internet access for a user across a range of ip addresses? Assume I have 10 machines, and an account on all of them (called customer).

1. Is it sufficient if I disable ssh and set the net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0  in sysctl.conf?
2. How can I ensure that the customer cannot change these rules?
3. Is there a simpler way to do this for all 10 machines, rather than physically run these commands on each machine?

Comment: You seem to be asking more than one question. We have a one question per question policy. But you can ask as many as you like. I have answered the question: How do I easily configure multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a configuration management tool.

Some examples are:

- chef
- puppet
- ansible

simpler tools are:

- pssh (parallel ssh)
- some other similar tools

See also revision control system, they are good to use in conjunction with configuration management.